# Find the shortest path between two vertices a and b in a specified graph. Graph's properties are in the description.

Tags: search, graph, shortest-path

Properties of graph:

- Graph has V vertices and E edges.
- It is connected, undirected and positive weighted.
- Graph has exactly one cycle.

The goal is to find the shortest path between two vertices a and b in O(V) time.

A link to a similar question if there's one will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Breadth-first search`, It is `O(V+E)`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Is there are way to do this in O(V) time?

Comment: O(V+E) is loosely considered O(V), but strictly, no I think it is impossible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: My guess is that the cycle in the graph is the key to reducing the runtime. Ideally if all the vertices were in the cycle then it should take O(V) time, since the number of vertices will be the same as the number of edges, however the question doesn't specify whether this is the case or not.